# .net 6 IActionFilter override of ActionExecutedContext HttpContext.Response.StatusCode not applying

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

I have just upgraded from .net core 3.1 to .net 6. I have an action filter which is hit after any calls to my API controllers, to override the response code based on the outcome of the API call (internal validation reasons). The code executes, but the response is still coming back as 200. This worked fine on .net core 3.1, is there something else I have to do on .net 6?

```
public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
{
    if (context?.Result != null)
    {
        var actionResultObject = context.Result as ObjectResult;

        if (actionResultObject != null && actionResultObject.Value != null)
        {
            if (actionResultObject.Value is MyResult result)
            {
                if (result.StatusCode != (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    switch (result.StatusCode)
                    {
                        case (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest:
                            context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
                            break;
                        case (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound:
                            context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
                            break;
                        case (int)HttpStatusCode.UnprocessableEntity:
                            context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.UnprocessableEntity;
                            break;
                        default: break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not related to the problem but please prefer [early exit](https://medium.com/swlh/return-early-pattern-3d18a41bba8) over this level of nesting.

Comment: Did you perform some debugging? Do you know at which `if` does the framework exits from your method?

Comment: @PeterCsala It exits at the correct point, but the resulting response code does not seem to apply, when it appears to in the method while debugging.

Comment: Have you tried to set the `context.Result` instead? Like this: `new StatusCodeResult((int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);`

Comment: Have you had a chance to try out my proposed alternative?